# Sumar variable para dos meses en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo el siguiente dataframe y necesito obtener las sumas bimestrales de enero y febrero para la variable precipitaciones. Lo hice para los años. Este es el código que utilicé

```
df.mensual <- df %>%
group_by(anio,mes,codigo) %>%
summarise(precip.mensual = sum(lluvia,na.rm="TRUE"))

filtering = filter(df.mensual, mes<3)
```

Lo que necesito es sumar los meses de filtering para cada año y codigo. Luego hacer una tabla que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
         1980 1981 1982 1983
----------------------------------------------------
codigo1   A    A    A    A
codigo2   A    A    A    A
codigo3   A    A    A    A
```

donde estan las A que esten las sumas bimestrales de enero y febrero para cada año y codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se puede solucionar así

```
#Se filtran los meses de interés
filtering = filter(df.mensual, mes<3) 

#Se crea un dataframe bimestre que agrupa el filtro anterior por año, luego los suma.
df.bimestral<- filtering %>%
    group_by(anio,codigo) %>%
    summarise(precip.bim = sum(precip.mensual,na.rm="TRUE"))
```

Luego el resultado es el siguiente

```
 anio codigo precip.bim
1   1910  87585        160
2   1911  87585        124
3   1912  87585        161
4   1913  87585         21
5   1914  87585        202
```